# Wait for message result from user like JOptionPane

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, wait, joptionpane

I want to my custom message class to behave the same way like JOptionPane in the following snippet does:

```
int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
     null, 
     "Is the weather beautifull?", 
     "Question", 
     JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION
);
if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
    // do something in response to yes...
} else {
    // do something in response to no...
}
```

So what I exactly want is, that I create my own message object, show it and the react on the button press done by the user in pseudo code like this:

```
show my question message;
wait for user button press without blocking UI thread;
do something depending on which button the user pressed;
```

I tried serverall things to have my message box  acting like the **JOptionPane** with **Futures**, **Wait/Notify** etc, but I always ended up in blocking my UI thread.

What is `JOptionPane`'s secret to do this? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html):

> A Dialog can be modal. When a modal Dialog is visible, it blocks user
>   input to all other windows in the program. **JOptionPane creates
>   JDialogs that are modal**. To create a non-modal Dialog, you must use
>   the JDialog class directly.

See [modal window](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window):

> ...requires users to interact with it before they can return to
>   operating the parent application

About the implementation, I guess that swing blocks the EDT and creates another thread for the modal dialog.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand, that JoptionPan as dialog blocks all other user input, but how is it done that the thread waits for the reply? Or better ask, how can i make my thread wait for a result without blocking the ui thread?

Comment: Ok i solved it, here is an code example for my solution: http://open-sourced.de/show_article.php?articleid=61